Token_2022 and mpl_token_metadata test issues
I'm having some issues with running tests locally against a program I created. Its based off mint_nft.rs from this repo but I've updated it to use the token_2022 program.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::metadata::mpl_token_metadata::{
    instructions::{
        CreateMasterEditionV3Cpi, CreateMasterEditionV3CpiAccounts,
        CreateMasterEditionV3InstructionArgs, CreateMetadataAccountV3Cpi,
        CreateMetadataAccountV3CpiAccounts, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs,
    },
    types::{CollectionDetails, Creator, DataV2},
};
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    metadata::Metadata,
    token_2022,
    token_interface::{Mint, Token2022, TokenAccount},
};

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = user,
    mint::decimals = 0,
    mint::authority = mint_authority,
    mint::freeze_authority = mint_authority,
)]
    mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
    seeds = [b"authority"],
    bump,
)]
    /// CHECK: This account is not initialized and is being used for signing purposes only
    pub mint_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: This account will be initialized by the metaplex program
    metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: This account will be initialized by the metaplex program
    master_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = user,
    associated_token::mint = mint,
    associated_token::authority = user
)]
    destination: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
    associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
}

impl<'info> CreateCollection<'info> {
    pub fn create_collection(&mut self, bumps: &CreateCollectionBumps) -> Result<()> {
        let metadata = &self.metadata.to_account_info();
        let master_edition = &self.master_edition.to_account_info();
        let mint = &self.mint.to_account_info();
        let authority = &self.mint_authority.to_account_info();
        let payer = &self.user.to_account_info();
        let system_program = &self.system_program.to_account_info();
        let spl_token_program = &self.token_program.to_account_info();
        let spl_metadata_program = &self.token_metadata_program.to_account_info();

        let seeds = &[&b"authority"[..], &[bumps.mint_authority]];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_program = self.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = token_2022::MintTo {
            mint: self.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: self.destination.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer_seeds);
        token_2022::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
        msg!("Collection NFT minted!");

        let creator = vec![Creator {
            address: self.mint_authority.key().clone(),
            verified: true,
            share: 100,
        }];

        let metadata_account = CreateMetadataAccountV3Cpi::new(
            spl_metadata_program,
            CreateMetadataAccountV3CpiAccounts {
                metadata,
                mint,
                mint_authority: authority,
                payer,
                update_authority: (authority, true),
                system_program,
                rent: None,
            },
            CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs {
                data: DataV2 {
                    name: "DummyCollection".to_owned(),
                    symbol: "DC".to_owned(),
                    uri: "".to_owned(),
                    seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                    creators: Some(creator),
                    collection: None,
                    uses: None,
                },
                is_mutable: true,
                collection_details: Some(CollectionDetails::V1 { size: 0 }),
            },
        );
        metadata_account.invoke_signed(signer_seeds)?;
        msg!("Metadata Account created!");

        let master_edition_account: CreateMasterEditionV3Cpi = CreateMasterEditionV3Cpi::new(
            spl_metadata_program,
            CreateMasterEditionV3CpiAccounts {
                edition: master_edition,
                update_authority: authority,
                mint_authority: authority,
                mint,
                payer,
                metadata,
                token_program: spl_token_program,
                system_program,
                rent: None,
            },
            CreateMasterEditionV3InstructionArgs {
                max_supply: Some(0),
            },
        );
        master_edition_account.invoke_signed(signer_seeds)?;
        msg!("Master Edition Account created");

        Ok(())
    }
}


My test file is practically the same as the repo but this is with TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID being passed into token program here
I can deploy the program so I feel like maybe it's some config issue with my Anchor.toml maybe.
error logs:
  1) mint-nft
       Create Collection NFT:
     
  Error: 
      at Function.parse (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:250:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:282:37)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

  2) mint-nft
       Mint NFT:
     
  Error: 
      at Function.parse (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:250:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:282:37)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

  3) mint-nft
       Verify Collection:
     
  Error: 
      at Function.parse (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:250:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:282:37)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1_bufferutil@4.0.8_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)



error Command failed with exit code 3.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Here is the repo if you would like to try it out locally, https://github.com/rtwhite10/token_2022_nft
Appreciate any advice, thanks!!

Could you also post the error logs

from what i can see, in your git you dont have the metadata program locally.
I answered the question below. How to make it work.

getAssociatedTokenAddressSync
The default value is TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID. You should change it to TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID.
export function getAssociatedToken2022AddressSync(
  mint: PublicKey,
  owner: PublicKey,
  allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
  programId = TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): PublicKey {
  if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer()))
    throw new TokenOwnerOffCurveError();

  const [address] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [owner.toBuffer(), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
    associatedTokenProgramId
  );

  return address;
}


Thanks @EthanOK! I tried that and it is still failing the test. I might post the repo here in a bit to make it a bit easier to troubleshoot.

Hey the reason its failing its because you didnt dumped the metadata program.
When running locally you need to:
first if you haven't dumped the program you do :
solana program dump -u d metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s metadata.so

Then you start your validator with:
solana-test-validator -r --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s metadata.so

Have a nice day ser.

Where you able to get the tests to pass locally? I'm still unable to get the tests to pass even with the metadata dump.

well i only checked the files and since u said it u were testing locally and the repo didnt had the metadata program file, it was impossible to work locally.
